# Return object property value inside a list, starting from a string

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core, object, field

I have a list of objects where every object has a specific color.
That list is defined under a unique variable as well,

```
List<obj> listofobjs = new List<obj>();
```

What I'm trying to do is starting from a string such as:

```
"listofobjs[2].Color"
```

Identify the object list, and the color of the object 2 there.

So far I'm able to return the list with this:

```
 string startpoint = "listofobjs[2].Color";
 List<obj> test = (List<obj>)this.GetType().GetField(startpoint.Split('[')[0]).GetValue(this);
```

But with test, I'm not being able to assign the [2] and Color from the string.
I can use

```
MessageBox.Show(test[2].Color);
```

But well, anyone understand this is not really pratical. How can I from the string return the list index 2, and the property Color that us there?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just to be clear - you want to parse the text string "listofobjs[2].Color" to return the `Color` property value of the element at index point 2 in a `List` of `obj` types?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: Get you give a bit more information around how this is to be used? So when you say "I have a list of objects" could this be any object, or is it always one with a Color for example? Is the list passed into a method for example along with the string? Is it a static list?

Comment: Yes, it's a static list, and there's always a color, all the objects have the same type of properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to retrieve your needs in console app, but seems `GetProperty` works, not `GetFied`
obj.cs

```
    public class obj
    {
        public  string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

Test.cs

```
    public class Test
    {
        public static List<obj> listofobjs { get; set; } = new List<obj>()
        {
            new obj(){Color="red"},
            new obj(){Color="blue"},
            new obj(){Color="white"},
            new obj(){Color="black"},
        };

        public void show(string startpoint)
        {
            var name = startpoint.Split('[')[0];
            var index =Int32.Parse( startpoint.Split('[')[1].Split(']')[0]);
            var subProperty = startpoint.Split('.')[1];

            List<obj> test = (List<obj>)this.GetType().GetProperty (name).GetValue(this);
            var result = test[index].GetType().GetProperty(subProperty).GetValue(test[index]);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```

Test Result
[image]

Comment: In this case I have to specify the color property. The aim is that it is read from the string startpoint

Comment: @desiredness I modify the code.